# Why is #field_parents empty in nested, multi-step form?

Tags: webforms, forms

I'm using [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform), [Fieldgroup](http://drupal.org/project/fieldgroup) and [Multistep](http://drupal.org/project/multistep) with D7.

Ultimately I'd like to create a hierarchically-grouped list of all the submitted values and display on the last step of the multi-step form, with the following format:

- Page 1

  - Question 1 Label

    - Question 1 Response
  - Question 2 Label

    - Question 2 Response
  - Question 3 Label

    - Question 3 Response
- Page 2

  - Question 4 Label

    - Question 4 Response
  - Question 5 Label

    - Question 5 Response
  - Question 6 Label

    - Question 6 Response

When I inspect the `$form` object, however, I see the fields each listed, but `$form['field_my_question']['und'][0]['#field_parents']` is an empty array.

How can I identify from the `$form` object which fields belong on which page of my multistep form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exactly `#field_parents` is for, but the information about field grouping is in `$form` (which, it turns out, is an array, not an object) several times over, in `$form['#groups']`, `$form['#fieldgroups']`, and `$form['#group-children']`.